# NSCollectionView Delegate Method on Select Header

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

The latest update to NSCollectionView allows the delegate to detect the selection of items with

```
- (NSSet<NSIndexPath *>*)collectionView:(NSCollectionView*)collectionView shouldSelectItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSSet<NSIndexPath*>*)indexPaths
```

and

```
- (void)collectionView:(NSCollectionView*)collectionView didSelectItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSSet<NSIndexPath*>*)indexPaths
```

, among others.

However, insofar as I can tell, these methods only detect the selection of `NSCollectionViewItem` objects, and not any present header or footer views.

Are there any delegate methods to detect the selection of the header and/or footer views? If not, what is the best way to implement this detection?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed these delegate methods are only for selecting items. If you want to do something when the header of footer view is clicked, you can add a gesture recognizer to those views yourself and hook it up to an IBAction on your controller.